# How to share a Swift object among Objective-C projects in Xcode workspace?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

**TLDR: There are two projects in a workspace. In one project there is a Swift object instance that implements an Objective-C protocol. How to share it among two projects in the workspace and make it accessible in mm files in those projects?**

I have a workspace with 2 projects A and B, where B is a framework and A depends on it. I need to share a Swift object that's created in A among A and B. I have tried doing it with a static variable and with a class implementation - but failed -- it seems that each of the projects gets its own version of everything. I have almost no experience with C++ and Objective-C/Swift, so I might be missing something obvious.

Here's how my code goes:

```c
// [ Project A, file Header.h ]

#ifndef Header_h
#define Header_h

// the Swift object must extend this protocol
@protocol CallsProxySingleton
-(void) someImportantMethod
@end

// --- way 1 of attempting to pass the instance: static variable

id<CallsProxySingleton> variableInstance = NULL;

void SetVariableInstance(id<CallsProxySingleton> api) {
    variableInstance = api;
}

// --- way 2 of attempting to pass the instance: class

@interface FrameworkLibApi : NSObject
+(void) registerAPIForNativeCalls:(id<CallsProxySingleton>) aApi;
@end

// this is used from Swift to install the singleton instance
@implementation FrameworkLibApi
static id<CallsProxySingleton> api = NULL;
+(void) registerAPIForNativeCalls:(id<CallsProxySingleton>) aApi {
    api = aApi;
}
+(id<CallsProxySingleton>) getApi {
    return api;
}
+(instancetype) getSelf {
    return self;
}
@end

#endif
```

```swift
// [ Project A, file CallsProxySingletonSwiftImplementation.swift ]

class CallsProxySingletonSwiftImplementation : NSObject, CallsProxySingleton {
    func initialize() {
        // --- way 1
        SetVariableInstance(self)
        // --- way 2
        NSClassFromString("FrameworkLibApi")!.registerAPIForNativeCalls(self)
    }

    // implementing CallsProxySingleton
    func someImportantMethod() {} 
}
```

```cpp
// [ Project A, file NativeInterfaceA.mm ]

extern "C" void SomeMethodThatsCalledFromCppCode() {
    // !!! this prints correct values: all pointers are non-null after the CallsProxySingletonSwiftImplementation had been called
    NSLog("pointers A: variable=%p, framework.api=%p, framework.self=%p", variableInstance, [FrameworkLibApi getApi], [FrameworkLibApi getSelf])
}
```

```cpp
// [ Project B, file NativeInterfaceB.mm ]

extern "C" void SomeOtherMethodThatsCalledFromCppCode() {
    // !!! this prints all null pointers (0x0) except for [FrameworkLibApi getSelf] which prints a different pointer than in project A
    NSLog("pointers B: variable=%p, framework.api=%p, framework.self=%p", variableInstance, [FrameworkLibApi getApi], [FrameworkLibApi getSelf])
}
```

The printout looks like this:

```
pointers A: variable=0x281e98980, framework.api=0x281e98980, framework.self=0x102bf6c88
pointers B: variable=0x0, framework.api=0x0, framework.self=0x10d6352c0
```

So, it all looks like my header file is re-interpreted twice and the second "instance" of it that's compiled in project B has its own set of variables that is totally unrelated to those in project A. The `[FrameworkLibApi getSelf]` returning another pointer only confirms this suggestion. Neither setting the global variable nor class helped to share the passed instance. In terms of Xcode workspace organization, the `[ Project A, file Header.h ]` file is added to project B by reference without copying.

As a 3rd way I've also tried moving the `[ Project A, file Header.h ]` file into a separate project C, and make projects A and B depend on framework C, but it gave absolutely the same result.

Question: How do I share the intended singleton instance of a Swift object across the projects in the workspace?